# LinkedIn oauth failing with no error

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn authentication to log in into my iOS app. It was working fine until few days back. It suddenly stopped working without any changes in the code.

When a user tries to log in via oauth, it just fails with the error message - `Domain=LIALinkedInERROR Code=2` and no localised description. However, authentication via LinkedIn app works. I've tried searching on the internet for similar issue but couldn't find anything related. I have also tried it on other apps on play store and its the same with those apps too. Has LinkedIn changed the API's or something?